# How to calculate or technique UIBezierPath control point smooth shape

Tags: ios, path, shapes, uibezierpath

How to calculate or technique `UIBezierPath` control point smooth shape.
Each control point has to move. But its shape remains as it is.
i tried but it is not smooth 
I dont know where I can get a complete algorithm or examples? Please help me out
Thank you.

ex.
[Example Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e1zgH.png)

Answer (score 1):

What you want is basic knowledge of bezier curves. First of all smoothness depends on whether it is a quadratic curve or cubic curve. Smoothness increases as number of control points increases.
[Basic description of cubic bezier curve.](http://cubic-bezier.com/#.17,.67,.6,.03)

And this link will help you to control points.
[Calculating control points.](http://www.spaceroots.org/documents/ellipse/elliptical-arc.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

I don't remember exactly from school right now, but when u want transition smooth you have to make 2 points of bezier curves same for smooth transition.